# What causes apps to crash on resume after a long time in background?

Tags: iphone, background-process, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm finding that after my app has been in the background for a while, (half hour + maybe) it crashes immediately on resume.

Crash log reveals that it is EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but I'm at loss for how to debug this one, because I don't know what gets released when my app goes to background (for a long time in particular). (Exception codes are 0x0000000 repeated)

Is there any documentation on this / can anyone give insight about what they did to fix this in the past?

While we're at it, is there a way to test this without waiting for hours before each try? Some way to simulate whatever it is that is happening to my app?

Thanks

### Update

I just read a bit more closely, and there's something here about a timer, I added some stuff that uses timers recently to my app, could this give more info? (See item 12)

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32858a1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x337013b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x336f9bf8 abort + 72
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30504a64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3068f06c _objc_terminate + 104
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30502e36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30502e8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x30502f5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3068dc84 objc_exception_throw + 64
9   MarsCrash                       0x0000be88 0x1000 + 44680
10  MarsCrash                       0x00020646 0x1000 + 128582
11  Foundation                      0x327196ce __NSFireDelayedPerform + 362
12  CoreFoundation                  0x334e7a40 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
13  CoreFoundation                  0x334e9ec4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 844
14  CoreFoundation                  0x334ea83e __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3347aebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3347adc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
17  GraphicsServices                0x311a5418 GSEventRunModal + 108
18  GraphicsServices                0x311a54c4 GSEventRun + 56
19  UIKit                           0x31b90d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
20  UIKit                           0x31b8e800 UIApplicationMain + 664
21  MarsCrash                       0x00002558 0x1000 + 5464
22  MarsCrash                       0x00002500 0x1000 + 5376
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common case for such situations is a call to an object that was released due to low memory warnings. EXEC_BAD_ACCESS — accessing to over-release object according to Apple's source (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1367/) You can find an actual source of the problem by taking a crash logs from your device and symbolizing it to an actual code strings in your product. I assume that knowing the class and method and code line number will give you a preliminary understanding what goes wrong in your code. Please, review following apple's article to understand further details — http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html

For an advanced topics on debugging following link maybe also very useful — http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html Actually Apple provides a ton of difference ways to debug such type of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed caused by a memory hit, you can try running it on the simulator, which has a menu item which lets you send your app a simulated memory warning.  Your app will try to do all the things it does during a real memory warning, and that might help you find your bug.  Also, look at running with NSZombies enabled  You might want to check out this page -- I find it very helpful:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease

Comment: Tried that, narrowed it down to most likely not caused by a memory hit, helpful nonetheless, that simplifies things

Comment: I'd be looking for something that you autoreleased, then specifically released it, then the autorelease released the dead memory.  It looks like you're crashing in the main event loop, which usually happens when the autorelease pool gets drained.